Is there a VBA method for extracting the original server path of an Excel file when working from a local temp file
Im trying to SaveAs a file that is stored on a server in a different file format. The sub folders that the file is stored in on the server wont be consistent so I cant simply write the path in as a string I need to be able to extract it dynamically.
The true path of the file is:
smb://xxx.xxx.x.xx/Jobs24/Graphic Group/164626/_data/FileName.xlsx

But when I use ActiveWorkbook.FullName I get:
/Users/oliver/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.Excel/Data/Documents/FileName.xlsx

Is there a method that will pull the true path? Since ActiveWorkbook.Save works as intended I assume that information is in there somewhere.
I've tried using fso.get and Workbook.FullName but they only pull the local temp path. All the documentation I find is for finding the local file path when I need the server file path. Or the documentation is about finding out the server path manually and then writing it as a string. I cant do that since the exact path wont always be the same.

Did you try ThisWorkbook.Path?  It should return the address akin to the FSO object.

I did. Im working out of a different workbook on the same server as the one referenced in the original post but i just tried it and got this:
/Users/oliver/Library/Group Containers/UBF8T346G9.Office/User Content.localized/Startup.localized/Excel
So even the local temp file format is not consistent.
